# Apache Ant JUnit tests fail, but pass in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, ant, junit

I have set up an end-to-end component test in Junit. It tests that objects generated at application startup are received at the other end of my application before they are sent over the network. I assert that the the number of objects received are the same as those generated. To be clear, this is only testing within the single application component. The network is mocked out.

When I run this test in Eclipse IDE, I send 4 and receive 4. When I run the test from Apache Ant, I send 4 but only 3 are received.

Does anybody know what this could be caused by? The test is probably run quicker with Ant, but my application is single threaded, so I don't see how this would make a difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: more precisely, how do you manage the two ends ? How do you manage ending of your tests ? There is a possibility it stops before end.